# Maximizing window and layout pass

Tags: java, javafx, layout

So goal here is to use custom `ScrollBar` for `ScrollPane` without having trouble with layout when maximizing/minimizing window.

Consider example program:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Layout extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        BorderPane main = new BorderPane();
        main.setPrefSize(800, 600);

        BorderPane center = new BorderPane(); // begin center
        center.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        main.setCenter(center); // end center

        BorderPane left = new BorderPane(); // begin left

        ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane();
        pane.setFitToWidth(true);

        Pane p1 = new Pane(); // child 1
        p1.setPrefSize(200, 100);
        p1.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.YELLOW, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        this.makeResizable(p1);
        Pane p2 = new Pane(); // child 2
        p2.setPrefSize(200, 100);
        p2.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        this.makeResizable(p2);
        VBox content = new VBox(10, p1, p2); // content in scroll pane
        pane.setContent(content);

        // replace normal bars
        pane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        pane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);

        // with custom
        ScrollBar sb = new ScrollBar();
        sb.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        sb.minProperty().bind(pane.vminProperty());
        sb.maxProperty().bind(pane.vmaxProperty());
        sb.visibleAmountProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(content.heightProperty()));
        sb.managedProperty().bind(sb.visibleAmountProperty().lessThan(1.0)); // bar should be managed when it is needed (content too long)
        sb.visibleProperty().bind(sb.managedProperty()); // and also visible only when managed
        sb.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(pane.vvalueProperty());

        left.setCenter(pane); // content
        left.setRight(sb); // scroll bar
        main.setLeft(left); //end left

        Scene scene = new Scene(main);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    // Simple for testing
    double prevY;
    boolean dragging;

    // Makes node resizable on drag.
    private void makeResizable(Region region)
    {
        region.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e ->
        {
            this.dragging = true;
            region.setPrefHeight(region.getHeight());
            this.prevY = e.getSceneY();
        });
        region.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, e ->
        {
            if (!this.dragging) return;
            region.setPrefHeight(region.getPrefHeight() + (e.getSceneY() - this.prevY));
            this.prevY = e.getSceneY();
        });
        region.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, e -> this.dragging = false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It will produce GUI with `ScrollPane` on the left with a custom `ScrollBar` that appears when content (2 nodes `p1` and `p2`) exceed bounds. In order to make it easy to test - both `p1` and `p2` are made resizable when dragging them with mouse (try it). While the `ScrollBar` appears and works as expected, there is a flaw in layout if we would start maximizing and minimizing window.

For example:

1. Start program
2. Resize content so `ScrollBar` appears, but not too
   much (make it so that when you maximize it, it will be in bounds)
3. Maximize window - you will notice that bar might have disappeard, but "empty space" appears.
4. Now, if you would somehow make refresh (e.g by resizing content again), bar would disappear due to layout pass update.

Other bug:

1. Start program and maximize.
2. Resize content so it is still contained in maximized window, but is big enough that when you minimize, it will exceed bounds.
3. Minimize
4. Notice how `ScrollBar` is misplaced.

There are few other bugs if you would try other stuff, but all originate from the fact that when you maximize/minimize this happens (using 1st example):

1. `ScrollBar` is managed and visible (considering content exceeds).
2. Maximize
3. Window is resized layout is calculated (using old values - managed=true && visible=true)
4. Layout happens, everything is in place, all properties receive update, including `sb.visibleAmountProperty()` making `ScrollBar` set managed and visible to false (since they are bound, see code).
5. `ScrollBar` becomes invisible and unmanaged, but layout already happened, and will not re-run.

How do I make it work with window maximizing? How else could I bind `ScrollBar` so it doesn't break when maximizing? Please note that we talk about maximizing, not resizing (which works).

Answer (score 0):

I found one workaround, but it doesn't seem like absolutely best thing to do, if there is more proper one - please share.

```
sb.managedProperty().addListener(e -> Platform.runLater(() -> content.requestLayout()));
```

Since this will be ran "later" (and since also on main thread which 1st should finish previous layout), this will cause relayout to happen.

Why is it not best? Well for one it would be called also when not really needed (while not maximizing) causing double layout (and we can't really resove this with some if statement).